# How can GIMP 2.8 have two different icons simultaneously?

Tags: application-development, packaging, gimp

In Unity dash GIMP 2.8.10 has a icon and uses a different one in launcher.

GIMP in Dash

[image]

GIMP in Launcher

[image]

I searched for GIMP in "File System" and got this.

[image]

How can this be done while packaging other apps?

Comment: Which version of GIMP are you using? AFAIK gimp only uses one icon.

Comment: Could you attach a screenshot?

Comment: This may be because icons in Launcher are resized.

Comment: IMO This may because of theme or desktop wallpaper.

Comment: I have added another picture which clearly proves that they are different

Comment: @terdon They are different. Look closer at the ear.

Comment: The answer is here http://askubuntu.com/a/73075/72216

Comment: Even if icons were shipped in `ico` files, no one would force you to use the same image for every resolution (which `ico` files contain multiple of). It seems prudent to use lower-detail versions for lower resolution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Take a look inside of `/usr/share/applications/gimp.desktop` file. You will see that the value of `Image` field is set to `gimp`. So, there is not given an absolute path for the GIMP icon. This means that the system will look for the icon most probably in `/usr/share/icons`. But there are more icons for GIMP, and **the right icon will be chosen depending on the theme and on the resolution at which this should be displayed**:

```
locate gimp.png
/usr/share/app-install/icons/gimp.png
/usr/share/icons/HighContrast/16x16/apps/gimp.png
/usr/share/icons/HighContrast/22x22/apps/gimp.png
/usr/share/icons/HighContrast/24x24/apps/gimp.png
/usr/share/icons/HighContrast/256x256/apps/gimp.png
/usr/share/icons/HighContrast/32x32/apps/gimp.png
/usr/share/icons/HighContrast/48x48/apps/gimp.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/gimp.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/apps/gimp.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/gimp.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/gimp.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/gimp.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/gimp.png
```

Finally, in the Launcher is chosen (most probably - depending on your settings) `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/gimp.png` file and in the Dash is chosen `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/gimp.png` file. If you will open these files, you will see that these look exactly like in your images.

Comment: That's why the bigger icon is visible when the launcher size is 64.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Exactly.